# Preventing simultaneous downloads of same file from same user

Tags: apache, file, download, ip-address

I'm looking into making an apache module that would prevent any user from downloading the exact same large file multiple times.

This is the logic I have in mind:

```
- Get IP address and if it's not in database, store it and allow download
```

If IP address exists, then:

```
- If current requested file matches previously requested file, show error
- Upon completion of download, remove IP address from database.
```

I plan to capture the end of the download via an output filter (or should I use the log_transaction hook?).

The problem with this idea is that hackers could change their IP address at any time and therefore two different IP addresses could download one copy of the exact same file simultaneously.

How do I rectify this whole situation so that no multiple downloads of the exact same file run simultaneously for multiple IP addresses that belong to hackers?

If anyone has a solution, can you provide some very basic pseudo code so I can update my apache module accordingly?

Comment: Can you any other identifier like remote user or any session id cookie to keep track of user?

Comment: I was thinking long and hard about password protecting the downloads since only certain users are allowed to download them but I talked to the guy who is funding/owning the server and he says he is against that because the people who use the downloads have almost no computer knowledge and he believes the prompt for a username and password would be too much for those users. I will talk to the guy again about this issue, but if there are any answers without the need to identify the user then I'll go with those first.

Comment: I want to add that his solution so far is to rename the files that are always being downloaded but to me, that's not a solution.